# Eliminate [unet] since absolutely identical to [unity3d-unet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unet) is absolutely, exactly the same thing as [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet).

The description for "unity3d-unet" is better and clearer and the tag is better and clearer.

**Suggest moderator to eliminate "unet"**

[unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unet) 114 Open Qs, 6 watchers

> UNET is short form of unity networking .Use this tag to ask question related to Unity3d networking.

[unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) 147 Open Qs, 29 watchers

> UNET is the native Unity3D network system.

Both: 20 Open Qs.

Neither tag has enough qualified users to propose and carry a synonym suggestion without mod assistance.

Comment: given the number of questions, making them synonyms seems a better call.

Comment: This change has been reverted; see [The synonym mapping \[unet\] to \[unity3d-unet\] is causing U-Net (deep neural network) questions to be silently mistagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417797/208273) and [The tag \[unity3d-unet\] is widely misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419609/208273).