# The synonym mapping [unet] to [unity3d-unet] is causing U-Net (deep neural network) questions to be silently mistagged

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

All these people use a specific *neural network* called "U-Net". They **try** to tag their questions as `unet` but someone decided to make `unet` an alias (or something...) to [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet), so instead of being denied the use of the tag, or warned, or anything, they're **silently** getting their question mistagged.

So now there are a ton of questions that are tagged wrongly, and nobody appears to monitor that tag and do the necessary housekeeping.

I don't know what should be done. I'm just reporting the situation.

Comment: having unet as an alias made sense up until now, and it still arguably does. What we need instead is a proper tag for the neural net. It's not silent, though. Tag aliases show under "see also", the tag entry itself still _clearly_ says `unity3d-unet`.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372240/4099593 ... _someone decided to make_ ... I wonder who that might be.

Comment: Maybe adding a [[tag:u-net]] tag specifically for the neural network would be useful? Then, at least, users would have to pick the tag that fit the question the best.

Comment: whatever you do, if someone types `unet`, that should not default to either choice (it does right now), but the user should have to actively pick from the choices.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine It's [a synnoym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d-unet/synonyms); if someone tries to add it to a question it will be "remapped" to the "correct" tag. It's silent in the sense that it doesn't ask them if that's what they meant, it just goes ahead and changes it, and it's extremely easy not to notice it doing so.

Comment: @CodyGray I think you're over-estimating a) the usefulness of the platform's tag UI; and b) the amount of thought the average user puts into their tags. There's no facility I know of to ask "did you mean X or Y", and no way anyone would guess that adding a hyphen would change the meaning. On the desktop site, you get a tiny pop-up with the tag description, which is easy to miss; on the mobile view, it doesn't show at all.

Comment: Yes, I am regularly guilty of over-estimating the likelihood of people paying attention to what they are doing. Unfortunately, if we can't assume that, we're out of options here. Mods can't blacklist tags, and while tag warning pop-ups do exist, setting them up requires assistance from a CM and isn't likely to happen (or even be worth it) for a tag with far fewer than 500 questions in total.

Comment: for the "dnn" tag, this was solved. "dnn" isn't a tag anymore, and it's not a synonym either, but both [tag:dotnetnuke] and [tag:deep-learning] somehow get suggested because the "dnn" string occurs in their descriptions (or their synonyms). if the same could be done to "unet", I'm sure that'd at least prevent the careless mistags. -- I wonder also what could be done to fix the mistagged questions.

Comment: Perhaps you could create [tag:u-net], go through the 429 (at present) questions and retag where appropriate (must be done manually in any case), then a mod can remove [tag:unet] as a synonym and have, as you mentioned, "unet" be in the description of both [tag:u-net] and [tag:unity3d-unet]

Comment: "deep-learning", "neural-network", and "computer-vision" are already tags. In my opinion a u-net tag is too specific seeing as u-net is a specific deep-learning architecture. its like adding a DFS (breadth-first search) tag instead of just using the algorithm, or graph-algorithm tags, when DFS is bound to be an acronym for something else as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started a [retagging effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419609/the-tag-unity3d-unet-is-widely-misused) to remove the [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) tag from questions that are not about Unity, and replace it with [unet-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unet-neural-network) where appropriate. We retagged roughly a quarter of the questions from that tag. Ryan M also removed the tag synonym as part of this process, which should prevent the situation from re-occurring. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419629/530160) for discussion of these changes.