# The tag [unity3d-unet] is widely misused

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The tag wiki for [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) says this:

> UNET is the native Unity3D network system. It is the short form of unity networking. Use this tag to ask questions related to Unity3d networking.

But in practice, roughly a fourth of the questions misuse the tag. They use the tag to talk about [U-Net, the neural network image segmentation technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-Net).

Here are a few searches that can be used to identify mistagged questions:

- [Tagged with [unity3d-unet], and not any of [unity3d] [c#] [multiplayer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet%2b-unity3d%2b-c%23%2b-multiplayer)

  197 questions. Probably some false positives in this search.
- [Tagged with [unity3d-unet] [image-segmentation]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet+image-segmentation)

  56 questions.
- [Tagged with [unity3d-unet] [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet%2bpython)

  87 questions.

Can we clean this up, and drop the [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) tag from questions which are not about Unity?

Comment: It probably doesn't help that [[tag:unet]] was made a synonym of [[tag:unity3d-unet]]... appears [it was synonymized back in 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372240/eliminate-unet-since-absolutely-identical-to-unity3d-unet). Now that it seems to somewhat consistently lead to confusion, the synonym has likely outlived its usefulness. I think we should probably create a tag specific to U-Net to retag these mistagged questions to if it doesn't already exist (a cursory search didn't bring any up).

Comment: @zcoop98 How about [tag:unet-neural-network] ? It's under the length limit and fairly clear.

Comment: I added [unity3d] to the questions that were missing it, as appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Proposal**: merge the [unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unet) and [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) tags to retag all existing questions, remove the synonym, then create a new [unet-image-segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unet-image-segmentation) tag to apply to the image segmentation questions.

**Update 2022-08-07**: The tags have now been merged and the synonym is deleted.

Comment: I think the name "unet-image-segmentation" makes more sense than the tag I suggested. After thinking about it some more, the reason why both UNET and U-Net have net in the name is that it's short for "network." So putting "network" in the name, like "unet-neural-network" is not doing any disambiguation work.

Comment: KISS: `unet-cnn` = U-Net convolutional neural network?

Comment: note: the new tag turned out to be **[tag:unet-neural-network]**. some use it for more than just segmentation, so it's one of the better options.